# FTP: Increase transfer speed

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, filezilla

I have a VPS with symetric 100mbps speed (guarantee). My connection can up to 300mbps. But when I transfer files per ftp (FileZilla), I cant transfer more than ~2MB/s per file. So if i transfer four file simultaneous, I have 8MB/s. My question is, is there any solution to transfer one file with 8MB/s of speed ? Is this the server or my computer who need to be configure ? Thanks Thomas

Comment: Is the remote end on a low-capacity connection, or throttling you so you don't hog all their bandwidth?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a server setup issue to me, could you give us a little more information about your setup in this context?

Comment: like I said, I can upload 5 files at 1.5MB/s each file. 
I installed proftpd package. It is a VPS on ubuntu with 100mbps. And if I donwload via ssh some file to the server I download at 10MB/s.

Comment: You've just said ssh has no such limit, so the issue is in either  the FTP server or client configuration. Make sure Filesilla has no limits set and check the ftp server configuration.

Comment: I agree with you, but in FileZilia I have not set a limit and on my server there is no line who defined speed limit. Thank for your answser